What is the syndrome in Hastings and Haah honeycomb code?
In the honeycomb code proposed by Hastings and Haah, by measuring 2-body checks and multiplying these values, they obtain the values of plaquette stabilizers. In the decoding, do they use only the values of plaquette stabilizers as a syndrome similar to the situation where we use the values of gauge operators to obtain the values of stabilizers? Or, can we use the values of 2-body checks for decoding?

Only one round of two-body check doesn't tell you anything, and you need multi-round of check results for the decoding purposes.

It's actually pretty varied.
There are three edge types: X, Y, and Z. But for the purposes here it makes more sense to label them geometrically: the edge type cut along the top and bottom boundary (V), the edge type cut along the side boundaries (H), and the bulk edge type (B). When you run the honeycomb code cycle, you will measure in the order BHV then BVH then BHV then BVH and etc.
Near the time boundaries, there can be individual edge measurements that form detectors all on their own or as part of a pair or a triplet. In the bulk, it depends on which type of edge and where you are in the cycle. Sometimes you compare six edge measurements, sometimes you compare ten, usually you compare twelve. We tried to make a diagram of this in arXiv:2202.11845, but I don't think we were too successful at conveying the complexity in a simple way:






Ultimately what it comes down to is, because the cases are so varied, you just end up taking them one at a time. Check if stim.Circuit.count_determined_measurements is larger than stim.Circuit.num_detectors + stim.Circuit.num_observables, see that it is, find another one you missed near the boundary. Repeat until done.
Note that crumble includes a honeycomb code circuit with correct detector annotations as one of its example circuits. You can use that to try to find the detectors for yourself and check against a known-good solution.
